# UINavigation titleView bug

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, snapkit

if I set a search bar to the navigation titleView, like

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = self.searchBar
```

, but I set it's frame by using autolayout like:

```
self.searchBar.snp_makeConstraints { make in
        make.left.equalTo(leftSpace)
        make.right.equalTo(-leftSpace)
        make.top.equalTo(10)
        make.height.equalTo(44)
}
```

, and then it will cause broken if I push to another view controller.

And if I set it's frame by using this way:

```
self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(leftSpace, 0, screenSize.width - 2 * leftSpace, 44)
```

it runs well...

Anyone can tell me why? Thx...

Answer (score 0):

TitleView's layout is managed by navigation controller. The constraints you've added to your view will be ignored when added to titleView. If you want to fully customized the navigation bar, I suggest to create your own view.

Comment: Thx first. But I can see the title view is correctly show in the navigation bar, and if I push to another view controller, then broken.